# Using react with cloud firestore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to figure out how to get cloud firestore working with a react app.

I have found [this tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/complete-firebase-authentication-react-tutorial), which uses react with realtime database, and have gotten it to load. Now I'm trying to figure out what changes I need to make to get it working with cloud firestore.

In my firebase.js, I have:

```
import app from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import firestore from "firebase/firestore";

class Firebase {
  constructor() {
    app.initializeApp(config).firestore();
    this.auth = app.auth();
    // this.db = app.firebase.database()
    this.db = app.firebase.firestore();

  }  

    doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
      this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);  
    doSignInWithEmailAndPassword = (email, password) =>
      this.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);  
    doSignOut = () => 
      this.auth.signOut();
    doPasswordReset = email => 
      this.auth.sendPasswordResetEmail(email);
    doPasswordUpdate = password =>
      this.auth.currentUser.updatePassword(password);

    // *** User API ***
    user = uid => this.db.ref(`users/${uid}`);
    users = () => this.db.ref('users');  

}
export default Firebase;
```

Then, in my form, I'm trying this:

```
import { withFirebase } from '../../../components/firebase';

onSubmit = event => {
    const { username, email, passwordOne } = this.state;

    this.props.firebase
      .doCreateUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, passwordOne)
      .then(authUser => {
        // Create a user 
        return this.props.firebase
          .user(authUser.user.uid)
          .set({
            username,
            email,
          });

      })
      .then(authUser => {
        this.setState({ ...INITIAL_STATE });
        this.props.history.push(ROUTES.INITIAL_PROFILE);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error });
      });
      event.preventDefault();
  }
  onChange = event => {
    this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };
```

The import withFirebase has:

```
import FirebaseContext, { withFirebase } from './Context';
import Firebase from '../../firebase.1';
export default Firebase;
export { FirebaseContext, withFirebase };
```

FirebaseContext has:

```
import React from 'react';
const FirebaseContext = React.createContext(null);

export const withFirebase = Component => props => (
  <FirebaseContext.Consumer>
    {firebase => <Component {...props} firebase={firebase} />}
  </FirebaseContext.Consumer>
);
export default FirebaseContext;
```

When I try this, I get an error that says:

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'firestore' of undefined**

The error message points to this line of the firebase config file:

```
this.db = app.firebase.firestore();
```

How can I get firestore working in a react app?

Comment: `app` is actually your firebase instance, so you have to do `app.firestore()` instead I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this:

```
this.db = app.firebase.firestore();
```

into this:

```
this.db = app.firestore();
```

[`initializeApp()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.html#initialize-app) returns type `App`, and inside `App` you can find the method `firestore()`:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.app.App.html#firestore